# Trying to get rid of the white border in the ComboBox

Tags: css, javafx, combobox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTWpU.png)

I am new to CSS and I am trying to get rid of the white space (as seen in the image) in the drop menu of the combo box... setting the background black didn't work... this is my CSS for the combo box

```
.combo-box  {
    -fx-border-width : 1 ;
    -fx-border-color : #29a8a6;
    -fx-text-fill: #29a8a6;
    -fx-border-radius: 50;
    -fx-padding : 0;
    -fx-background-color: #29a8a6;
    -fx-background-radius: 50;
}
.combo-box .list-cell{
-fx-prompt-text-fill : #29a8a6;
 -fx-text-fill: #29a8a6;
 -fx-background-color: black;
 -fx-padding : 2;
 -fx-cell-border : 0;
 -fx-border-width: 0;
 -fx-border-radius: 50;
  -fx-background-radius: 50;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get answers I recommend you to learn to use Stack Overflow code snippet (provide HTML, CSS, JS etc), or if you aren't familiar you can use a free service like JSFfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ and post here the link to your fiddle. We cannot help you if you do not provide the full code in your scenario because we cannot inspect the code!

Comment: @mariusfv This is a JavaFX question; there is no HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: @mariusfv as James said, is javafx ...

Comment: That said, providing a complete example (a [mre]) that others can use to see the problem and test out solutions would make it more likely you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the white space in the drop down menu you can add this to your css file:

```css
.combo-box .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

PS:
Whenever you are not sure which elements styling you need to change, you can make use of [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) to find out the element.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the problem was the listview in the combo-box , so setting the insets to 0 solved my problem

```
.combo-box {
-fx-background-color:#29a8a6;
-fx-background-radius : 40;
}
.combo-box .list-view {
-fx-prompt-text-fill : #29a8a6;
-fx-background-color : black;
-fx-background-radius : 40;
-fx-insets : 0;
}
.combo-box .list-cell{
-fx-prompt-text-fill : #29a8a6;
-fx-text-alignment : CENTER;
-fx-background-radius : 40;
-fx-background-color : black;

}
```